# I know this code in Android, but I'm having trouble in getting the same output in Swift language

Tags: java, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Code is :

```
DatabaseReference newDatabaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("loccheck").push(); 
newDatabaseReference.getKey();
```

I want the pushed key without actually setting the data in the Firebase for iOS (Swift)

Answer (score 1):

You may need `childByAutoId` swift's equivalent to android's `push`

```
let key = mDatabaseReference.child("loccheck").childByAutoId().key
```

see [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)